# Get tkinter root to disappear on a Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working with Python 3.7 on a Mac, version 10.14.6. I'm using a simple little tkinter screen to get a username and password so as not to hard-code it. My code is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk

username = ''
password = ''


def get_username_and_password() -> list:
    """
    This function sets the username and password, if either is empty.
    :return: List as [username, password]
    """

    # GUI code to obtain username and password
    root = tk.Tk()

    # Prompt for the user to enter the username.
    username_label = tk.Label(root, text='Username:')
    username_label.pack()

    # String entry box to get the username.
    username_string_entry = tk.Entry(root, text='',
                                     justify=tk.CENTER,
                                     width=28)
    username_string_entry.pack()

    # Default will be Adrian Keister.
    username_string_entry.insert(0, 'm210028')

    # Prompt for the user to enter the password.
    password_label = tk.Label(root, text='Password:')
    password_label.pack()

    # String entry box to get the password.
    password_string_entry = tk.Entry(root, 
                                     text='',
                                     justify=tk.CENTER,
                                     width=28, 
                                     show='*')
    password_string_entry.pack()

    # Make the password string entry box get the focus.
    password_string_entry.focus_set()

    def on_enter(event=None) -> None:
        """
        This function gets the string entries, and quits this tiny
        GUI.
        :param: event: A throw-away argument, because we want to be
                       able to call this function on button click or
                       when the user hits Enter.
        :return: Nothing.
        """
        global username
        global password
        nonlocal username_string_entry
        nonlocal password_string_entry
        nonlocal root

        # Get the strings from the Entry widgets.
        username = username_string_entry.get()
        password = password_string_entry.get()

        # Quit the GUI.
        root.withdraw()
        root.destroy()

        return None

    # Make sure the KP Enter or Return key locks in the address.
    root.bind('<Return>', on_enter)
    root.bind('<KP_Enter>', on_enter)
    root.title('Please enter your username and password:')

    # Run the little GUI.
    root.mainloop()

    return [username, password]


print(get_username_and_password())
```

The code definitely gets the username and password, but it's buggy: the screen doesn't disappear when I hit the enter/return key unless I also exit Python. Any idea why this is happening? An additional note: the `root.withdraw()` does not appear to minimize the tkinter window, either, although that's definitely what it's supposed to do.

A note on OS's: in Windows 10 and Xubuntu Linux 16.04, this problem does not arise. I can run `python test_username.py` or do `import test_username` from inside Python, and it works as expected either way - from Windows or Xubuntu Linux.

Comment: Your code works fine for me on OSX when I add just enough code to be able to call your function and then run the code from the command line.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Hmm. Well, I get the problem when I'm calling this code from within PyCharm, either when running from another script or from using PyCharm's iPython terminal. If I call python or ipython from the command line and import the containing module, and then call this function, I still get the same problem.

Comment: Note that importing `sys` and putting `sys.exit()` after `root.destroy()` does make the screen go away; the problem is that this code is called in the middle of a script, and I can't have Python going away just then!

Comment: If the problem only happens in pycharm or only in iPython's terminal, you need to add those details in your question.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Well, maybe. What are the exact steps you're taking that don't produce the problem?

Comment: I ran `python the_script.py` from a terminal after adding just enough code to make it run.

Comment: So in your case, Python is exiting after you're done, right? When I exit ipython or python, my tkinter window always goes away. The problem appears to be that, for whatever reason, the code above does not make the tkinter window go away unless I also make Python go away. But making a tkinter window disappear without exiting Python is surely a very common use case.

Comment: It goes away when I run from a terminal. I can also open up a python prompt, import the code, and when I press return the window goes away without having to exit python.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Ok, well, there's something different in your environment from mine, because it behaves differently for me.

Comment: Part of the problem may be that you haven't provided a [mcve] so I have to guess at part of the process. It would help if you could create a complete [mcve] which we can run from a command-line prompt without having to edit the code. It would also help to let us know if you're using the python provided by OSX or whether you're using some other version of python.

Comment: I have made a couple of changes to the code recently; is it a MWE now?

Comment: You can answer your own question by saving the code from the question to a file, and then run `python the_file.py`. The answer is "no".

Comment: Ok, it's a MWE. I can confirm that if I run `python test_username`, the window goes away. If I run `python` and import `test_username`, the window does not go away.